# Error Scripting Possible mistaken empty statement and Unexpected symbol `override'

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and I have come across an issue called a "Possible mistaken empty statement"  and " Unexpected symbol `override'"now I have done a lot of research on this topic,however this only produces more warnings and more errors that I currently do not know the solution to, I would very much appreciate the help, the language I am using is C#.

here is my script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FighterStateBehavior : StateMachineBehaviour {

    public float horizontalForce;
    public float verticalForce;


    protected Fighter fighter;

    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, 
        AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) {
        if (fighter == null) {
            fighter = animator.gameObject.GetComponent<fighter> ();

        fighter.body.AddRelativeForce (new Vector3 (0, verticalForce, 0));
}
    override public void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, 
        AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) {
        fighter.body.AddRelativeForce (new Vector3 (0, 0, horizontalForce));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`override` should be after the modifier `public`, not before. Also

```
if (fighter == null) {
        fighter = animator.gameObject.GetComponent<fighter> ();
```

should be

```
if (fighter == null) {
        fighter = animator.gameObject.GetComponent<fighter> ();}
```

You have  an opening curly bracket `{` for the block after `for` and no closing corresponding curly bracket `}`.

Comment: I'm glad you fix it.